# Rails .where call to database shows images in development (mysql), but not production (postgres)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

When running the below command on my view in development, my images load perfectly. However, when I push everything to Heroku production, they don't appear. I know it is not a problem with my AWS images as I can call them elsewhere in my application using an @image instance variable. Does this have anything to do with Postgres using different types of calls on Rails?

```
<% if @location.brand.images.where(image_category: 'logo').take %> 
    <span class="logo-title brand-logo"><img src="<%= @location.brand.images.where(image_category: 'logo').first.image.logo %>"></span>
<% else %>
    <span class="logo-title"><%= @location.brand.brand_name %></span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be so many things, so the real answer to this issue is: change your development environment to use Postgres too.

One of the big differences between MySQL and Postgres is that MySQL is case-insensitive by default, whereas Postgres is case-sensitive. Could your string `"logo"` be a different case in your DB?

Comment: That did it! My strings were all capitalized. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, make sure you mark my answer as "Accepted" if it solved your problem.